# Android Twitter Sign In via native app

Tags: android, twitter, single-sign-on

Whatever examaples i've seen until now have twitter login implemented via the browser window. Isn't there a way to sign in via native twitter app in Android? Facebook does have such feature, what about twitter?

Comment: The answer to this is Twitter's Fabric SDK